# How can I internationalize my rails app (not translate)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rubygems

First off, yes I've read all the [rails documentation about I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) but it doesn't help me with what I want to do.

The app I'm developing will be international (in multiple languages) with user-generated content. I don't want to translate the user-generated content to different languages but I need to assign a "locale" to every piece of content.

Though, the static pages (about us, how it works, contact us, etc.) will be translated.

I've looked at [globalize3](https://github.com/galetahub/globalize3#readme) but from what I understand it only solves my problem for static pages.

I guess I could simply add a column "locale" to all my user-generated content models but then I would need to chain a "where locale = current_locale" to every query. This will end up being heavy in the end.

Does anyone have other ideas? Maybe a filter for certain model queries could be devised, but I am still a new Rails developer and don't know if that is possible.

Many thanks!

Comment: Oops! I didn't even know I had to do that. I have went back and accepted the good answers. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Look at the refinery CMS, it handles what you're describing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it answers the question, specially because I have only a couple of months of Rails experience.
But, as far as I understand, Globalize3 can be used. [The Globalize3 RailCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3) may help to understand this.

Globalize3 deals with the translation of data that are in database. To translate data that are not in the database you should use I18n that is explained in [this RailCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n-revised)

The question is old but I hope it helps someone else :)